# virt-sandbox error creating an OS container with lxc backend in virt-manager

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, lxc, virt-manager

I am attempting to create an OS container through virt-manager with the lxc backend. virt-sandbox exits without any information on why it fails. Where can I find logs for it? Can I run virt-sandbox with verbose logging through virt-manager?

I'm using Pop OS 20.04.

Link to the virt-manager log file: [https://paste.sr.ht/~ananth/db49ba5e1991adc261c93e2900bf04ed33433887](https://paste.sr.ht/%7Eananth/db49ba5e1991adc261c93e2900bf04ed33433887)

Comment: Have you tried to run manually: `virt-sandbox --security=inherit -c qemu:///session --name=bootstrap_3557 -m host-bind:/mnt=/home/ananth/.local/share/libvirt/filesystems/ubuntu:18.04 -- /bin/tar xf /home/ananth/.cache/virt-bootstrap/docker_images/d7c3167c320d7a820935f54cf4290890ea19567da496ecf774e8773b35d5f065 -C /mnt --exclude dev/* --exclude */.wh.* --overwrite --absolute-names` ?